# jQuery: How to check a DOM element has inline style

Tags: jquery, dom

I want to remove unwanted nesting.

How can I select from DOM, elements with this form:

```
<div style="display: block;">
..
</div>
```

It seems like a tight filtering like:

```
var unwanted_nest = $('.webform-client-form').find('div:not([id])').filter('div:not([class])');
```

will only display forms like:  ..

Comment: Unfortunately no as this select all divs

Comment: can target the contents and use `unwrap()` method if have a common class as child of DIV shown

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
$('div[style="display: block;"]');
```

[fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/bipen/g7Pqr/)

however this selects all the div with attr `style= display : block` if this what you want

Comment: assumes no other inline style properties and spacing of `display: block` is exactly as shown. If use `$(selector).hide()` would have same style but spacing likely different. Not a reliable selector IMO

Comment: yes.. that is why i added the last however part ... :)... and yes the question included `How can I select from DOM, elements with this form:<div style="display: block;">..</div>` so the answer..:) :)

Comment: `var unwanted_nest = $('.webform-client-form').find('div[style="display: block;"]');
console.log(unwanted_nest, 'unwanted');`

It worked like this for me, thanks!